# How does TypeScript (Angular http client, get) work? (Retuning something without having a body)

Tags: angular, typescript

I was wondering, when I use the http client of Angular without any host, like this: `http.get('/api/users')` how the base url is determined. So I searched for the code in Github and found this: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/client.ts#L667

This looks like an interface to me. It defines a return value, but there is no body. I do know that TypeScript sometimes does things implicit like assigning attributes in the constructor, but here? How does this method(s) work?

I tried to search for it, but I am not sure what so search for. It would be great if someone could explain how this works.

Comment: It uses the domain name of the server your js is server from.

Comment: @nrgwsth I thought about it. But still: how does angular does anything when there is not body, at least for some of the get functions?

Comment: @Ctwx, if you're running Angular and an API in the same dominion (e.g. use the Angular template of .NET Core) you needn't write .get("http: // www. midominio.com/api/users") because you're execute in http:// www. midominio yet. It's equal that when you use a image.jpg, you can write < img src="images/miimagen.jpg" > or < img src=" http: // www. midominio.com/images/miimagen.jpg" >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is function overloading is a future of typescript

```
  get(url: string, options: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders | {[header: string]: string | string[]},
    observe?: 'body',
    params?: HttpParams|{[param: string]: string | string[]},
    reportProgress?: boolean,
    responseType: 'arraybuffer', withCredentials?: boolean,
  }): Observable<ArrayBuffer>;
```

and this the soure of get function

```
  get(url: string, options: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders | {[header: string]: string | string[]},
    observe?: HttpObserve,
    params?: HttpParams|{[param: string]: string | string[]},
    reportProgress?: boolean,
    responseType?: 'arraybuffer'|'blob'|'json'|'text',
    withCredentials?: boolean,
  } = {}): Observable<any> {
    return this.request<any>('GET', url, options as any);
  }
```

> Request url will look like this `baseUrl` + `/api/users`

Comment: Thanks. But how does the linked code work? Line 667 contains a definition of a function but no body? I have not found an implementation or something.

Comment: from line 677 to 868 are function overloadu 
 line https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/client.ts#L868 is the implimintation of get method @Ctwx

Comment: Oh, overloading. That makes sense. Thanks!